# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text_in_use' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I can set the variable and print it directly after if choice == 1. But if choice == 2 i cant print it out the text that was set, I get an error.

(UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text_in_use' referenced before assignment)

How can i fix this?

```
text_in_use = ''
encrypt_key = ''

def menu():
    choice = int(input("""1: Input text to work with
2: Print the current text
3: Encrypt the current text
4: Decrypt the current text
5: Exit
Enter Choice: """))

    if choice == 1:
       text_in_use = str(input("Enter Text: ")).upper()
       print("Text to use was set to:", text_in_use)
       menu()
    elif choice == 2:
        print(text_in_use) #this is where i get the error <-----
        menu()
    elif choice == 3:
        print("3")
        menu()
    elif choice == 4:
        #decrypt()
        print("4")
        menu()
    elif choice == 5:
        #exit()
        print("5")
        menu()

menu()
```

i just want it to print the text that was set.

Comment: move the `text_in_use = str(input("Enter Text: ")).upper()` before the `if` statement begins.

Comment: You're calling `menu()` again after each input, and the next execution of `menu()` doesn't remember the text that was entered in the previous execution.  It's probably best to rearrange your code so that all the logic happens within the same execution.

Answer (score 0):

-- Hi Linus,

Your variable

```
text_in_use
```

only is set if your first condition is met. So if your codes skips that condition and moves on to:

```
elif choice == 2
```

the variable hasn't been set yet.

Since, the function recursively calls itself after every option, you also can't add the variable before the first clause as I initially suggested.

**So I'm changing my answer to the following:**

*At this point I would also like to add that a function without any exit may not be what you ultimately want to use. So I commented out the recursive call in option 5.*

My suggestion is to use a simple class:

```
class Menu:
  def __init__(self):
    self.text_in_use = ''
    self.encrypt_key = ''

    self.build_menu()

  def build_menu(self):

    choice = int(input(
      """
      1: Input text to work with
      2: Print the current text
      3: Encrypt the current text
      4: Decrypt the current text
      5: Exit

      Enter Choice: 
      """
    ))

    if choice == 1:
      self.text_in_use = str(input("Enter Text: ")).upper()
      print("Text to use was set to:", self.text_in_use)
      self.build_menu()
    elif choice == 2:
      print(self.text_in_use)
      self.build_menu()
    elif choice == 3:
      print("3")
      self.build_menu()
    elif choice == 4:
      #decrypt()
      print("4")
      self.build_menu()
    elif choice == 5:
      #exit()
      print("5")
      # self.build_menu() do not call this again so it actually exits.

Menu()
```

Comment: The thing is that the user should only be able to set the variable from an input if they in the menu choose option 1 (first if statement). Then the text they set should be printed when menu is loaded again and they enter 2

Comment: @LinusRiesle-palgan changed the answer to reflect that. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark text_in_use variable as global. 
You reference it in function from outer scope

```
def menu():
    global text_in_use
    choice = int(input("your_text"))

   #rest of code
```